# How to run `docker-compose` web application on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm using an image annotation tool ([coco-annotator](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator) based on Vue.js) locally and I would like to run it on a AWS webserver, to be able to access it from anywhere.
The source code contains some docker files and can locally be run using

```
docker-compose up
```

Does someone know, what are the high-level steps to run this application on a AWS webserver?
AWS seems quite complicated as it has a million options, so I'd like to know

1. What "product" should I choose? ("EC2" (virtual machine)? "Elatic Beanstalk" (web application)?
2. What pre-installation should I choose? ("Docker - single instance"?)
3. How do I tell AWS, how to launch the command for the coco-annotator? (login via ssh and run the command manually? or is there some pre-configuration that enters the respective source folder automatically and runs docker-compose up on startup?)

**Solution**

- Select a AWS EC2
- As virtual machine chose "t2.micro" (free tier eligible) for example with Ubuntu 18.04
- Login to your EC2 virtual machine instance via ssh and run manually install the coco-annotator (or other software) -> note the local port that the server is running on
- make the IP-Adress to your ec2 instance permanent ([click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgfpduy5ZAo))
- make your EC2 instance accessible via the browser ([click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukdTGVVcqE0)) --> Add Rule for "TCP/IP" + access from anywhere
- `sudo apt-get install nginx` -> enter your domain in the default config file of nginx
- Use the AWS "Route 53"-Service to create a "hosted zone"
- Register a free domain, eg [here at freenom](https://my.freenom.com)
- On AWS - Route 53: "Create Record Set" -> Name: "www.yourWebdomain.com" Value: "yourAwsEc2IpAddress"
- note the nameservers provided by Amazon (ns-.awsdns-20.) and enter them as custom nameservers on the config page of your domain  provider (freenom). Do not use URL forwarding!
- now the communication between nginx, and your AWS EC2 instance should be working

Answer (score 1):

This is a very loaded question and you'd probably get a better response with a more direct question with an example.  With that said, if your app is containerized you can use ECS or Elastic Beanstalk.  If your application is stateless (you don't need local disk storage this is persistent between restarts of your application, you can still use a database or other services for storage) the easiest is probably ECS using Fargate tasks.

There are numerous blogs and tutorials online because, as you've already said, there are very many different types of applications, deployment and configuration options.  Start reading some blogs and the docs for using docker compose to deploy contained to AWS.

A place to get started might be here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html

Edit:

I see you cross posted here https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/issues/231. The OP there said they used a VM. In AWS this is an EC2 instance. The get started https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/wiki/Getting-Started#dedicated-servervps-setup also says this requires a dedicated server or VSP. That would also point to EC2. If you want to use ECS or Beanstalk you need to deploy a container. I don't know if this app supports running in a container and if you want to pursue that routeyour best place to ask is probably in that projects community not SO.

Comment: It's hard to come up with a narrow question, when AWS offers a plethora of options which each look like a 2h rabbit hole of wasted time, therefore the high level question. I'll have a look into the `fargate` option now, so thx. I'll get back, once I found a way through this jungle

Comment: I left an edit for you in my answer. SO is for answering specific programming questions not deployment/configuration questions for every application out there. This isn't a programming question, it is a deployment/configuration question for a specific application. This type of question is better for the community that supports the application in question. You were right to post in their GitHub repo and will probably get better support of their application from it's community.

Comment: Well your answer already helped me a lot, (while I could have wasted a lot of time, waiting for the github-answer). EC2 is up and running and accessible from anywhere using the correct settings. I will post the full solution here, once I have everything running and - if possible - reshape the question so it becomes more 'general purpose'. I still think SO is the best place to get help for this kind of issue though...

Comment: As the creator of the coco-annotator, I recommend you post questions directly to the github issues page, as the community is built around the repository (I also check the repository daily). If you go with a EC2 you will be running docker contains on the VM with docker-compose. You can deploy to Beanstalk/ECS (since the project is containerized), and you will need to use the docker-compose file as a guideline